# How to click on the nth pixel of an image with python (NOT WHAT YOU THINK)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui, pynput

I have some code to determine the location of every black pixel on the screen:

```
last_pixel = 0

time.sleep(0.01)
ss = pyautogui.screenshot()
ss.save(r"Screenshots\ss.png")
image = Image.open(r"Screenshots\ss.png", "r")
pixels = list(image.getdata())
for n, pixel in enumerate(pixels):
    if pixel == (0, 0, 0):
        print(pixel, n)
        last_pixel = n
```

However, this returns, for example, "(0, 0, 0) 2048576", and to click on a specific point on the screen, at least with pynput/pyautogui, you need an x, y kind of thing, how can i possibly click on a pixel of an image (screenshot) with simply a number like: *its the 2048576th pixel, click it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the size of your image (width x height), converting pixel number to [x, y] coordinates is a trivial math problem.

```
img_width = 1920
img_height = 1080

pixel_number = 2000

pixel_row, pixel_col = divmod(pixel_number, img_width)
```

I'm not sure whether the pixels are stored in row-major or column-major order. If they're stored in column-major order, all you need to do is:

```
pixel_col, pixel_row = divmod(pixel_number, img_height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshape your pixel list into the dimensions of the image and get the index of the pixel in that location.  For example

```
import numpy as np

# 150 pixel long array
a = np.array(range(150))
# If your images was 15 pixels wide by 10 tall find the coordinates of pixel 108
np.where(a.reshape((10,15))==108)
```

Output

```
(array([7], dtype=int64), array([3], dtype=int64))
```